# Zend_Cache_Exception: file Zend/Cache/Backend/Memcache.php not found in include_path

Tags: zend-framework, memcached, phpunit

I am developing a nice application that seems to be running fine, I've started to add some PHPUnit tests to the project.  However whenever I try and run a test I get the following error:

> Zend_Cache_Exception: file Zend/Cache/Backend/Memcache.php not found in include_path

When I look into that path of the file system, there is no Memcache.php, only Memcached.php.

The full stacktrace from the phpunit run looks like this.

> 1) IndexControllerTest::testIndexAction Zend_Cache_Exception: file
>   Zend/Cache/Backend/Memcache.php not found in include_path
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Cache.php:148
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Cache.php:94
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Cache/Manager.php:173
>
> /opt/www/development/app/application/Bootstrap.php:64
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:667
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:620
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:584
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Application.php:355
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:155
>
> /opt/www/development/app/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:136
>
> /opt/www/development/app/tests/application/controllers/IndexControllerTest.php:9

Any idea why this is being thrown when running unit tests but not when I run the application fully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the cache is `Memcached`, not `Memcache`. Without seeing your code I can't say why you don't get an error outside of unit testing. `Zend_Cache::_makeBackend()` will throw an exception if the file doesn't exist or the class isn't found.

Comment: Thanks after a bit of diffing arround I had named the cache type as Memcache not Memcached in my application.ini file.  Thanks for your help.